# PHP Use proc_open and capture stdout of 'echo' command

Tags: php, process, echo, proc-open

I've been searching around but haven't managed to find a direct answer to this question. At the outset I'll state that what I'm trying to achieve isn't necessarily particularly useful but the aim is partly to understand how PHP interacts with other processes and streams, etc.

At a shell terminal, you can run a command like `echo $USER` for example and it will output whatever is in the environment variable called `USER`.

I'm wondering if it's possible to execute this command and then capture the output from shell `echo` command using PHP's `proc_open` function.

This is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
$descriptors = [['pipe', 'r'], ['pipe', 'w'], ['pipe', 'w']];
$handle = proc_open('echo Hello world, $USER!', $descriptors, $pipes, null, ['USER' => 'guest']);
$world = stream_get_contents($pipes[0]);
```

`$world` is staying empty (i.e. `''`).

I have a couple of theories as to why it isn't working  [as well as a reason why each theory might be false following in square brackets] but I'm wondering if someone could either confirm one of them or offer another explanation as to why it's not working please?

---

**Theory 1**
The echo command terminates immediately before PHP has a chance to read the output. [Really? Is there no way to use proc_open to capture output from a command that terminates immediately? Maybe that's not what proc_open is for?]

**Theory 2**
echo is somehow treated as a shell built-in command rather than a standalone executable and that's why it behaves differently? [Linux provides an executable called echo in `/bin/echo`, couldn't it just use that one? Plus changing `echo` to `/bin/echo` doesn't solve the problem either]

---

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reading from `$pipes[0]`. This is `stdin`. You want to read from `$pipes[1]` which is mapped to `stdout` (and has the `w` flag for being written to):

```
$descriptors = [['pipe', 'r'], ['pipe', 'w'], ['pipe', 'w']];
$handle = proc_open('echo Hello world, $USER!', $descriptors, $pipes, null, ['USER' => 'guest']);
$world = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
var_dump($world);
```

Outputs

```
string(20) "Hello world, guest!
"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! 
Can't believe that was all it was. 

Actually this was a simplified extract from the original code, but knowing that this _does_ work has enabled me to figure out that my original problem was just that I wasn't waiting long enough to read the output from stdout, as I had also enabled non-blocking mode. 

I'll accept this answer and maybe this can be a useful reference for anyone else just learning how to use process IO and streams.